# Plotting multiple histograms in one 3d

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, histogram

I've got multiple vectors of which I would like to plot seperate histograms in the same figure. However, if I plot all histograms in the same 2D plot, the results become hard to interpret/distinguigh. Therefore I would like to plot them (detached) in 3D.

All I have right now is the following:

```
hist(A)
hold on
hist(B)
hist(C)
holf off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout [`bar3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) for 3D bar plots.